# Spark Scala - Read different parquet files with different schema and write to different output paths

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a parent folder with child folders, each children folder contain a parquet file (represent a  table), like that :

```
|Parent_input_folder:
|--- Children_folder1:
|      |--- file1.parquet
|--- Children_folder2 :
       |--- file2.parquet
```

The goal is to read from these folders and write to the output folders after transformations with spark scala:

```
|Parent_output_folder:
|--- Children_folder1:
|      |--- file1.parquet
|--- Children_folder2 :
       |--- file2.parquet
```

Note : each file have different schema to other

Have you some idea to do this in spark scala ?

Comment: What transformations you would like to apply? How do u apply transformations if you aren't aware of the schema?

Comment: is your input parquet file schema mergeable?

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this which will get you almost what you want is the combination of `input_file_path` and `partitionBy` as below:

```
val results = table
  .withColumn("path", input_file_name())
  .withColumn("path", concat_ws("\\", slice(split(col("path"), "/"), 8, 2))) // get the path in the format that you want

results
  .write
  .partitionBy("path") // partition by your path column
  .parquet("structured")
```

Good luck!